# Check Box selected attribute set regardless of value

Tags: php, html, browser

Try this at home:
Write a form to display a list of checkboxes in PHP:

```
$checkboxes = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3);
$html = "<html><body><form name=\"myForm\" action=\"this\" method=\"post\"><ul>Check Test";

foreach ($checkboxes as $id => $value)
{
     $checkVal = (isset($_POST['check_test'][$id])) ? 'true' : 'false';
     $checkList = "<li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_test[]\" id=\"$id\"
                   value =\"$value\" checked=\"$checkVal\" />$name = $value</li>\n";
}
$checkList .= "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
echo $html.$checkList."</ul></body></html>";
```

You will find that no matter what you put into the $checkVal assignment, when you hit submit, your checkboxes will all be checked. My workaround is to expand the $checkVal variable to set the entire "checked='' status to either something or nothing. I'm just surprised that Firefox (rather, Iceweasel) is only looking to see if the attribute is set at all. Why even have it if whatever it's set to is irrelevant?

Look at the source html. The selected attribute will display whatever you put into the checkval variable. The DOM specification states:
checkboxObject.checked=true|false

Here is my output:

```
<ul><li><input type="checkbox" name="check_test[]" id="one"
                       value ="1" checked="false" />one= 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_test[]" id="two"
                       value ="2" checked="false" />two= 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="check_test[]" id="three"
                       value ="3" checked="false" />three= 3</li>
```

And lo and behold! Every box is checked. Contrary to what I've explicitly expressed in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The false is ignored. If the check attribute exists the box is checked.

```
foreach ($checkboxes as $id => $value)
{
     $checkVal = (isset($_POST['check_test'][$id])) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
     $checkList = "<li><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_test[]\" id=\"$id\"
                   value =\"$value\" ".$checkVal." />$name = $value</li>\n;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post: "My workaround is to expand the $checkVal variable to set the entire "checked='' status to either something or nothing. "[br] I was merely pointing out that why bother have an attribute "equal" something and represent meaningless data in the DOM? No other input attributes operate that way. It's poor design and a kludge to save somebody from writing an extra 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: Selected is not the only, that are a number more like it. [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) for example. Yes it looks like kind of bad design but I think it is more a compatibility thing for old browsers. For most browser you can simply write selected and it will work but it is easier to implement if all tag attributes look the same way name="value".

Comment: Aha, thank you for clearing that up. As I was finishing my post, the thought occurred to me that this may all be  browser incompatibility. I'm mostly running IceWeasel which is supposed to be Mozilla 5 but it has it's tweaks and connundrums. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You are welcome. If everything is clear now, it would be polite to accept the answer to your question to close the topic.